XSLT Missing Segment issue after sorting
I have issue while sorting the segments, i need to sort segments Node/ITEM and Node/LINE segments separately,
Node/ITEM Sorting:  we need check if Node/ITEM exist then if Node/ITEM/LINE/FIER/VALUE is repeating in another Node/ITEM/LINE/FIER/Value where Type=Key1,if its repeating then based on ITEM/LINE/FIER/VALUE (Type=Key2)  we need to perform sorting.
Node/LINE Sorting: Same as above, if Node/LINE exists then based on Node/LINE/FIER/VALUE , we can do sorting.
i found almost similar example, but  XSLT is removing Node/LINE Completely, its able to do Node/ITEM sorting correctly.  Please review it once
Input:
<SBD>
    <DOCUMENT>
        <Field1> value1</Field1>
    </DOCUMENT>
    <Node documentStatus="True" date="2024-09-27">
        <ship>123</ship>
        <field2>345r</field2>
        <ITEM>
            <IDENT>
                <CODE>
                    <Value>67896789</Value>
                </CODE>
            </IDENT>
            <LINE number="1">
                <CIDENT>
                    <name>12</name>
                    <FIER>
                        <VALUE>555</VALUE>
                        <TYPE>Key1</TYPE>
                    </FIER>
                    <FIER>
                        <VALUE>XYZ</VALUE>
                        <TYPE>Key2</TYPE>
                    </FIER>
                </CIDENT>
            </LINE>
        </ITEM>
        <ITEM>
            <IDENT>
                <CODE>
                    <Value>3243</Value>
                </CODE>
            </IDENT>
            <LINE number="2">
                <CIDENT>
                    <name>12</name>
                    <FIER>
                        <VALUE>444</VALUE>
                        <TYPE>Key1</TYPE>
                    </FIER>
                    <FIER>
                        <VALUE>BBBB</VALUE>
                        <TYPE>Key2</TYPE>
                    </FIER>
                </CIDENT>
            </LINE>
            <Segment1>
                <subsegment>
                    <value>123</value>
                </subsegment>
            </Segment1>
        </ITEM>
        <ITEM>
            <IDENT>
                <CODE>
                    <Value>0870</Value>
                </CODE>
            </IDENT>
            <LINE number="3">
                <CIDENT>
                    <name>12</name>
                    <FIER>
                        <VALUE>444</VALUE>
                        <TYPE>Key1</TYPE>
                    </FIER>
                    <FIER>
                        <VALUE>No</VALUE>
                        <TYPE>Key3</TYPE>
                    </FIER>
                    <FIER>
                        <VALUE>AAA</VALUE>
                        <TYPE>Key2</TYPE>
                    </FIER>
                </CIDENT>
            </LINE>
        </ITEM>
        <LINE number="1">
            <CIDENT>
                <name>12</name>
                <FIER>
                    <VALUE>6382</VALUE>
                    <TYPE>Key1</TYPE>
                </FIER>
                <FIER>
                    <VALUE>REA</VALUE>
                    <TYPE>Key2</TYPE>
                </FIER>
            </CIDENT>
        </LINE>
        <LINE number="2">
            <CIDENT>
                <name>12</name>
                <FIER>
                    <VALUE>5678</VALUE>
                    <TYPE>Key1</TYPE>
                </FIER>
                <FIER>
                    <VALUE>CBA</VALUE>
                    <TYPE>Key2</TYPE>
                </FIER>
            </CIDENT>
        </LINE>      
        <LINE number="3">
            <CIDENT>
                <name>12</name>
                <FIER>
                    <VALUE>5678</VALUE>
                    <TYPE>Key1</TYPE>
                </FIER>
                <FIER>
                    <VALUE>BCA</VALUE>
                    <TYPE>Key2</TYPE>
                </FIER>
            </CIDENT>
        </LINE>
        <rdtime>123</rdtime>
           <advice>123</advice>
        <newfield>213</newfield>
    </Node>
</SBD>




Desired output:
<SBD>
    <DOCUMENT>
        <Field1> value1</Field1>
    </DOCUMENT>
    <Node documentStatus="True" date="2024-09-27">
        <ship>123</ship>
        <field2>345r</field2>
        <ITEM>
            <IDENT>
                <CODE>
                    <Value>67896789</Value>
                </CODE>
            </IDENT>
            <LINE number="1">
                <CIDENT>
                    <name>12</name>
                    <FIER>
                        <VALUE>555</VALUE>
                        <TYPE>Key1</TYPE>
                    </FIER>
                    <FIER>
                        <VALUE>XYZ</VALUE>
                        <TYPE>Key2</TYPE>
                    </FIER>
                </CIDENT>
            </LINE>
        </ITEM>
        <ITEM>
            <IDENT>
                <CODE>
                    <Value>0870</Value>
                </CODE>
            </IDENT>
            <LINE number="3">
                <CIDENT>
                    <name>12</name>
                    <FIER>
                        <VALUE>444</VALUE>
                        <TYPE>Key1</TYPE>
                    </FIER>
                    <FIER>
                        <VALUE>No</VALUE>
                        <TYPE>Key3</TYPE>
                    </FIER>
                    <FIER>
                        <VALUE>AAA</VALUE>
                        <TYPE>Key2</TYPE>
                    </FIER>
                </CIDENT>
            </LINE>
        </ITEM>
        <ITEM>
            <IDENT>
                <CODE>
                    <Value>3243</Value>
                </CODE>
            </IDENT>
            <LINE number="2">
                <CIDENT>
                    <name>12</name>
                    <FIER>
                        <VALUE>444</VALUE>
                        <TYPE>Key1</TYPE>
                    </FIER>
                    <FIER>
                        <VALUE>BBBB</VALUE>
                        <TYPE>Key2</TYPE>
                    </FIER>
                </CIDENT>
            </LINE>
            <Segment1>
                <subsegment>
                    <value>123</value>                  
                </subsegment>
            </Segment1>
        </ITEM>
        <LINE number="1">
            <CIDENT>
                <name>12</name>
                    <FIER>
                    <VALUE>6382</VALUE>
                    <TYPE>Key1</TYPE>
                </FIER>
                <FIER>
                    <VALUE>REA</VALUE>
                    <TYPE>Key2</TYPE>
                </FIER>
        </CIDENT>
    </LINE>
    <LINE number="3">
        <CIDENT>
            <name>12</name>
            <FIER>
                <VALUE>5678</VALUE>
                <TYPE>Key1</TYPE>
            </FIER>
            <FIER>
                <VALUE>BCA</VALUE>
                <TYPE>Key2</TYPE>
            </FIER>
        </CIDENT>
    </LINE>
    <LINE number="2">
        <CIDENT>
            <name>12</name>
            <FIER>
                <VALUE>5678</VALUE>
                <TYPE>Key1</TYPE>
            </FIER>
            <FIER>
                <VALUE>CBA</VALUE>
                <TYPE>Key2</TYPE>
            </FIER>
        </CIDENT>
    </LINE>
    <rdtime>123</rdtime>
   <advice>123</advice>
    <newfield>213</newfield>
</Node>
</SBD>

XSLT I used is below:
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
  
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="Node">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="* except (ITEM, LINE, rdtime)"/>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="ITEM" group-by="LINE/CIDENT/FIER[TYPE='Key1']/VALUE">
        <xsl:sequence select="sort(current-group(), (), function($l) { $l/LINE/CIDENT/FIER[TYPE='Key2']/VALUE })" />
      </xsl:for-each-group>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="LINE" group-by="CIDENT/FIER[TYPE='Key1']/VALUE">
        <xsl:sequence select="sort(current-group(), (), function($l) { $l/CIDENT/FIER[TYPE='Key2']/VALUE })" />
      </xsl:for-each-group>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="rdtime,advice,newfield"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>

Please review it once

What about the other child elements like rdtime or ship or rfield, where do the need to be sorted to? Why does the input have to rdtime elements but the desired output has only a single one?

i have modified the input, my bad i mistakenly added rdtime twice,  under Node segment, ship or field will be in the same position as it will come only once in input

I think if you know the two child elements you want to group and/or sort and the other elements are in a known position you can just make sure you process them all separately and of course you can apply-templates to the attributes of Node:
  <xsl:template match="Node">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, * except (ITEM, LINE, rdtime, advice, newfield)"/>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="ITEM" group-by="LINE/CIDENT/FIER[TYPE='Key1']/VALUE">
        <xsl:sequence select="sort(current-group(), (), function($l) { $l/LINE/CIDENT/FIER[TYPE='Key2']/VALUE })" />
      </xsl:for-each-group>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="LINE" group-by="CIDENT/FIER[TYPE='Key1']/VALUE">
        <xsl:sequence select="sort(current-group(), (), function($l) { $l/CIDENT/FIER[TYPE='Key2']/VALUE })" />
      </xsl:for-each-group>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="rdtime, advice, newfield"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template> 


Thanks Martin, its working with initial example i have given, but in the end i have two more fields called advice, newfield, i declared that XSLT but in the output one copy of that fields is being sent to right after Node field, also Node has attributes which is getting suppressed,  Can you please review once, i have updated input, output and XSLT code

@Pavan, see whether the edit helps, in the end, if you have attributes, you need to push them through the identity transformation set up by mentioning them in the apply-templates  sequence selector. And if you explicitly process some elements after the grouping then you want to exclude them with except before the grouping.

Thank you Martin for your assistance and help. It's working as expected
